# How do I use express routing (server side) when I use react in express and share node global variable in react like:languages etc?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

How do I use express routing (server side) when I use react in express  and share node global variable in react like:languages etc?

How do I access node global variables in react with using express routing (server side) instead of react routing (client side)?

Comment: define the routes in express and then in react request to these routes simple. Better if you manage identical routes on both sides

Comment: You need to combine both

React will only be used as a view engine and then you need to create api in node to talk with the server end .

Comment: thank, Aniruddha Chakraborty .
but, there is no any other way to do this ?

Comment: I don't think so . because React is born to replace view engine! you just need to handover the data from server using API .

Comment: What kind of problems you're facing due to this ? @hemantkumar

Comment: In global variable of node to access with react.